# createGraphics change of color for dark mode

Tags: p5.js, interactive, webflow

Got a p5.js sketch that I want to update when I change the body color so I can use the animation in dark mode as well. However, when I implement the interaction for the body color changes the graphic fails to update its color. Not sure if I need to create a new function and then call it in Draw again?

```
//p5.js hero animation//

let font
let graphic

let body = document.querySelector("body")

let bodyTextColor = window.getComputedStyle(body).getPropertyValue("color");

function responsive () {

graphic = createGraphics(windowWidth / 1.1, windowHeight)

graphic.fill(bodyTextColor);
graphic.textSize(windowWidth * 0.4);
graphic.textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
graphic.textFont('GT cinetype');
graphic.textStyle(ITALIC);
graphic.text("aaaa", windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2);

}


function setup () {
  var myCanvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  myCanvas.parent('p5-container');
  
    responsive();

  
}

function draw () {
    
    background("0, 0, 0, 255");

  const tileSize = 20

  for (let x = 0; x < 120; x = x + 1) {
    for (let y = 0; y < 60; y = y + 1) {

      const wave = 0.03

      const distortionX = sin(frameCount * wave + x * 0.5 + y * 0.2) * 30
      const distortionY = sin(frameCount * wave + x * 0.5 + y * 1.1) * 10

      const sx = x * tileSize + distortionX
      const sy = y * tileSize + distortionY
      const sw = tileSize
      const sh = tileSize

      const dx = x * tileSize
      const dy = y * tileSize
      const dw = tileSize
      const dh = tileSize

      image(graphic, dx, dy, dw, dh, sx, sy, sw, sh)
      graphic.fill(bodyTextColor);
    }
  }
  
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  responsive();

}
```

here is the link to the temporary site https://jaramillo-arango.webflow.io/

Comment: Currently your `responsive` function only gets called once on setup, and when the window SIZE changes. Not when the body color changes!

Comment: should I add that function to draw as well then? not sure how to call that when the bodytextcolor changes?

Thanks!

Comment: `draw()` gets called 60 times per second, so that's a bit too much for a function that only needs to be called when the body color changes. There is no default function in P5 to respond to changes in body color.  To help you out further I'd need to know HOW you change the body color in the first place.